# How to make SQL results display in different vertical columns?

Tags: php, mysql

So I have my results displaying, only they're displaying in 1 column down the webpage. I would like them to display in 5 columns

Heres my code

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM mytable LIMIT 5"; 
$result = mysql_query($query);

echo "<table>"; 

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){   
echo "
        <table width='100%' style='padding-right:50px; padding-left: 50px;'>

        <td><img id='dvdCovers' src='". $row['FIELD4'] ."'/>
        <br>

        <a id='tcMain'>". $row['FIELD1'] ." <a> ". $row['FIELD2'] ."</tc>
        <tr>

        </table>
";
```

Comment: You're creating a new table on each pass here.

Comment: you need to understand the logic behind your code first  inorder to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM mytable LIMIT 5"; 
$result = mysql_query($query);

echo " <table width='100%' style='padding-right:50px; padding-left: 50px;'>"; 

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){   
echo "<tr>
        <td><img id='dvdCovers' src='". $row['FIELD4'] ."'/></td>
        <td><a id='tcMain'>". $row['FIELD1'] ." <a></td>
        <td> ". $row['FIELD2'] ."</td></tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

Comment: I've no idea why your answer was downvoted; not my vote that's for sure.

Comment: I tried to upvote but can't due to new account. This definitely helped my code however, I think I need different tables for each "movie" lets say, so each table has a movie poster, movie name, year and that would be that table complete then I would like to replicate that table next to it (but with different data), like table cells, but tables. Thanks for the answer!